# Conditional logic in logger in dataweave for Mulesoft

Tags: mule, mule-studio, dataweave, mule-component, mulesoft

I need help on conditional logic in logger.

I am using attached code in logger processor but getting errors:

[image]

Comment: Where is the logger processor complete with the expression? And please use text, not screenshots for code.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to achieve something like below?

[image]

Update:

Try with the Logger content in the screenshot:

```
<logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" doc:id="a45f1214-f063-47bc-8c8f-a72b65b5633f" message='#[%dw 2.0
output  /java
var TxId="1"
---
if(!isEmpty(vars.TxType)) "Trx Id:" ++ TxId ++ " Trx Type:" ++ vars.TxType  else "Invalid Partner"]'/>
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, but I want to print 'OUTPUT' on console which you are showing using Logger processor. so I need to write if  else logic in Logger processor.  Please help on this.

Comment: The request is unclear. Please provide more details, including examples of the expected output, to which console do you refer (Studio Console tab, standard output in a terminal?).

Comment: @Ravi Did that answer your question ? The logger content is in the screenshot